# Using Python with Google People API otherContacts.copyOtherContactToMyContactsGroup method

Tags: python, google-api, google-contacts-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to use Python to execute a request to update contacts from 'other contacts'. I can create a request object like this

```
oRequest = servPeople.otherContacts().copyOtherContactToMyContactsGroup(resourceName = 'otherContacts/c5014863774837996295')
```

but I need to specify a copyMask, e.g. 'emailAddresses'

This documentation [Creating API requests and handling responses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/api-requests-responses)
seems to show how to specify the body for such a request, and according to this [Method: otherContacts.copyOtherContactToMyContactsGroup](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/otherContacts/copyOtherContactToMyContactsGroup#request-body)

I think the request body should be `{ "copyMask": 'emailAddresses' }` and the request object has this method, so I can specify  `oRequest.body = { "copyMask": 'emailAddresses' }`

but when I then try oRequest.execute(), I get this message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 977, in send
> self.sock.sendall(data)
> File "C:\Users***\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1012, in sendall
> with memoryview(data) as view, view.cast("B") as byte_view:
> TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - this does it:

```
body = {"copyMask": 'emailAddresses,names,phoneNumbers'}

result = servPeople.otherContacts().copyOtherContactToMyContactsGroup(resourceName = 'otherContacts/c5014863774837996295', body = body).execute()
```